# Highcharts read text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I'm new to JavaScript and HighCharts. I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I got lost.
I want to create a scatter chart with three lines. I need to read data from a text file, and the file looks like this:

> ```
> x   y1  y2  y3
> ```
>
> 1.02      1.00      6.70      8.19
>      2.04      1.00     13.30      8.19
>      3.06      1.00     13.50      8.19
>      4.08      1.00      9.60      8.19
>      5.10      1.00     14.60      8.19
>      6.12      1.00     19.20      8.57

So I need to plot three line with (x and y1), (x and y2), (x and y3)

And this is my HighCharts code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

            var options = {
            chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'scatter',            
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
            title: {
                   text: 'Demo'
                },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'Time, ns'
            },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
                },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
            text: 'Value'
            }
                },
                series: []
            };

            $.get('///plot.txt', function(data) {
                var lines = data.toString().split('\n');
                $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                    var item = line.split()});
            options.series[0].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
            options.series[0].data[1].push(parseFloat(item[1]));

    options.series[1].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
                options.series[1].data[1].push(parseFloat(item[2]));

                options.series[2].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
                options.series[2].data[1].push(parseFloat(item[3]));

            }, 'text')

            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            </script>
```

I feel I messed up the entire code. I'm sorry but I never wrote JavaScript before. Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

that's what you want to get : http://jsfiddle.net/z28vy/

Now a few comments

**Read doc**

You have to look at the HighChart documentation that is quite good, with live example on jsfiddle. Some are quite close to your use case (displaying data from data got with an AJAX call.)

What's peculiar in your need is to get raw text data, which force you into annoying parsing stuff.

**Understand what you are doing**

Even if your code could end up working, it looks like you are messing a bit with the sync/async story of your javascript. If you are a beginer that's a lot of things to learn at once. Not to mention you are trying to stick to jQuery style with anonymous functions...

**Indent !**

First thing, I do not know if it is just your post on here, or if you actually write code like that, but indent it properly ! It will show you a lot of problems at a glance. Especially when you are writing enclosed code (for example the success callback function of your ajax call.)

**Arrays**

Then, just a bit of logic : you have to know that although dynamic, arrays in javascript cannot have random access (read or write) on any non assigned slot. So when you are doing

```
options.series[0].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
```

you should have previously set options.series[0] which you didn't since your options object defines series as an empty array:

```
series: []
```

You can do that at the time of your ajax success method, or statically at options definition, depending on the flexibility you need in the number of series accross your use. I prefer you stay simple at first and do :

```
series: [{
            name: 'Serie 1',
            data: []
        },{
            name: 'Serie 2',
            data: []
        },{
            name: 'Serie 3',
            data: []
        }]
```

Like that you can access each of your 3 series like you did... well except that you have the same problem with data[0] which does not exist neither for the same reason. Anyway do not bother much because...

**First use your API as it goes**

The way you add points to your series is far too complex anyway. series has an addPoint() method, just use it ! So instead of

```
 options.series[0].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
 options.series[0].data[1].push(parseFloat(item[1]));
```

Just do

```
 options.series[0].addPoint([parseFloat(item[0]), parseFloat(item[1])]);
```

it's already easier to read :)

**jQuery is not magical, it is just logical**

Now the problem you have is your use of jquery $.each() I do not know if you just did not understand it or if you started to use it, then decided to hard-write your data handling to move on.

```
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var item = line.split()});
options.series[0].data[0].push(parseFloat(item[0]));
options.series[0].data[1].push(parseFloat(item[1]));
```

As you will clearly see if you start indenting and separate things, you do nothing more than splitting each line for no purpose there.

Just use what you get with your split. If we say we are putting the current serie number in serieIdx :

```
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var item = line.split(' ');
    if(item.length==4 && !isNaN(parseFloat(item[0]))) { // skip unwanted line such as header or empty line
        chart1.series[serieIdx].addPoint([parseFloat(item[0]), parseFloat(item[serieIdx+1])], false);
    }
});
```

That's it. You just to have to iterate through your 3 series and you are good to go.

**A side note about addPoint of serie in HighCharts**

Be careful that if you call addPoint with invalid data (such as an array of anything instead of numbers) there is no visible error raised, but it breaks something anyway. In my case, before I added the test

```
if(item.length==4...
```

And since I had also at first a '\n' at the end of the last line, the upper split gave me one last empty string, which obviously ended up as en empty items array after the inner split. Which triggered an addPoint([NaN, NaN]) that purely made the lines between dots disappear for the whole graph. Be careful to that !

**About the jsfiddle sample**

jsfiddle obviously does not allow AJAX get but provide a trick instead : POST data in a json that jsfiddle server will resend back in the answer after the given delay (in my example I put 3 seconds.)

http://jsfiddle.net/z28vy/

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's so detailed and very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read previous answer, since is pretty long, however I always advice to read tutorial from Highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json